# Error: Extra alignment tab has been changed to \cr. \end{split}

Tags: split

Using this code I get the error: "Extra alignment tab has been changed to \cr. \end{split}". Why so?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
 \begin{equation}
        \notag
        \begin{split}
    Ws & \leftrightarrow I^2(s, \varphi_{W}) \\
      I^2(s, \varphi_{W}) & \leftrightarrow I^3(s, \varphi_{W}, \varphi_{I^2})\\
        I^3(s, \varphi_{W}, \varphi_{I^2}) &  \leftrightarrow   I^4(s, \varphi_{W}, \varphi_{I^2}, \varphi_{I^3})
    & \ellipsesline
    \end{split}
    \end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `split` only supports up to one single `&` per row. You have two in the last row.

Comment: you have two `&` on the last line before `\ellipsesline` (which you have not said how it is defined)

Comment: How or where is `\ellipsesline` defined?